# ZF2 - Adding custom libraries / validator classes

Tags: php, zend-framework2, composer-php

I am trying to create a custom library and, specifically, a custom validator. I have created the following file

```
/vendor/tealbury/library/Tealbury/Validator/UsernameValidator.php
```

Which contains a class

```
class UsernameValidator extends \Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator { ... }
```

I have then added the following lines to composer.json

```
"autoload" : {
    "psr-0" : {
        "Tealbury\" : "vendor/tealbury/library"
    }
}
```

In my model, I then include the  validator like so

```
use Tealbury\Validator\UsernameValidator;
```

However, when I attempt to call

```
new UsernameValidator;
```

I recieve the following

```
Fatal error: Class 'Tealbury\Validator\UsernameValidator' not found in /usr/local/zend/var/apps/http/__default__/0/1.0.0/module/Application/src/Application/Model/Join.php on line 58
```

I have put this together using information from the Zend Framework 2 documentation and from a similar question asked here. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the autoload directive in composer.json, you don't need the trailing slash on the namespace name. Also, make sure your class is properly namespaced with `namespace Tealbury\Validator` at the top.